# Prove that if linear system $\bf Ax = O$ has a unique solution, then for arbitrary vector $\bf b$, $\bf Ax = b$ will have a unique solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> **Proposition** If linear system $\bf Ax = O$ ($\bf A$ is $n$ by $n$  square matrix) has a unique solution, then for arbitrary vector $\bf b$, $\bf Ax = b$ will have a unique solution.

---

My attempt:

> **Lemma 1**. If $\bf Ax = O$ has a unique solution, then $\bf x = O$

Suppose $\bf Ax = O$ and $\bf x = b$ where $\bf b ≠ O$. Because $\bf AO = O$, it follows that linear system $\bf Ax = O$ has at least two possible solutions, which a contradiction.

> **Lemma 2.** $\bf Ax = O$ has a unique solution $\bf x = O$ iff $\bf A$ is invertible

The $(\rightarrow$) side is a bit lengthy, hence for now we just assume that we've already proved lemma above.

Now to our main proposition:

Suppose $\bf Ax = O$ has a unique solution. By lemma 1 and 2, we conclude that $\bf A$ is invertible.

Consider linear system $\bf Ax = b$, where $\bf b$ is the arbitrary vector:

$$\tag 1\bf Ax = b \implies$$
$$\tag 2\bf A^{-1}x = A^{-1}b \implies$$
$$\tag 3\bf x = A^{-1}b$$

Therefore, for arbitrary vector $\bf b$, lin. system $\bf Ax = b$ will have a unique solution, namely $\bf A^{-1} b$. $\Box$

---

I believe that for the trivial proposition like the one above, more concise alternatives are available, but still, **is my attempt correct**?

Comment: Is $A$ a square matrix?

Comment: @Kavi, yes, sorry, I forgot to mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, assuming you prove lemma 2 correctly.

But you do not need lemma 2. In fact, you can go directly.

**Proving that $Ax=b$ has at least one solution**:

Let $X=\{Ax| x\in\mathbb R^n\}$.

Now, take any basis $\mathcal B=\{b_1, b_2,\dots, b_n\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$, and observe the  set $\mathcal {B'}=\{Ab_1, Ab_2,\dots Ab_n\}$. We will prove that $\mathcal B'$ is a linearly independent subset of $X$.

1. Clearly, $\mathcal B'\subseteq X$.
2. We now prove $\mathcal B'$ is linearly independent. Assuming that $$\alpha_1Ab_1+\dots\alpha_nAb_n=0$$ for some $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$, we see that that $$A(\alpha_1b_1+\dots\alpha_nb_n)=0$$ which means, since $0$ is the unique solution to $Ax=0$, that $\alpha_1b_1+\dots\alpha_nb_n=0$. Since $b_i$ are basis vectors, this means $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\cdots=\alpha_n=0$, therefore, $\mathcal B'$ is linearly independent.

From the two points above, we can conclude that the dimension of $X$ is at least $n$ (since it has at least $n$ linearly independent vectors), which means $X=\mathbb R^n$, and therefore, for each $b\in\mathbb R^n$, $b\in X$, and $b\in X$ is equivalent to $\exists x: Ax=b$.

**Proving that $Ax=b$ has at most one solution**:

Assume $Ax_1=Ax_2=b$. Then $Ax_1-Ax_2=0$ meaning that $A(x_1-x_2)=0$. But we already know that $Ax=0$ has a *unique* solution, which is $0$, so $x_1-x_2=0$ and $x_1=x_2$.
$$$$

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you prove more than what is asked: you prove that if the *homogeneous* linear system has a unique  solution, its matrix is invertible and you give the solution of the *non-homogeneous* equation. In my opinion, proving by contradiction lemma 1 is a bit too much.

Here is how I would prove what is asked in a short way:

Suppose we have (possibly equal) solutions:
$$\mathbf{Ax}=\mathbf{b},\qquad \mathbf{Ax'}=\mathbf{b}.$$ 
Then, by linearity, we deduce $\;\mathbf{A}(\mathbf x-\mathbf x')=\mathbf 0$, and by hypothesis, $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}=0$, i.e. $\;\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x'}$.

Comment: But here you have proved that if there existe a solution then is unique, bit you are not proving existence of the solution.

Comment: @HeMan: I took it for granted. But I can add another (more abstract) short proof of both.

Answer (score 0):

As $A$ is square matrix, say $nxn$ and $Ax=0$ implies that $x=0$, ir follows that $A$ is inyective. Because it is a square matrix, and its injective, it follows that is bijective (because as $dim(im(A)) + dim(ker(A))=n$ and that $ker(A)={O}$, then it follows that $dim(im(A)=n$ so $im(A)=\mathbb{R}^n$), then for each $b$, there exists unique $x$ such that $Ax=b$.

Comment: "Because it is a square matrix, and its injective, it follows that is bijective"... I'm not sure OP is allowed to assume this.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit rusty.

Lemma 1 is simple:

1. If $Ax=0$ has a unique solution, the solution must be $x=0$ as $x=0$ is a solution.

Lemma 2 is key:
2. $Ax=0$ has a unique solution (which must be $0)$ iff $A$ is invertible.

If $A$ is invertible, then applying the inverse of $A$ to $Ax=0$ gives $x=A^{-1}0 =0$.

If $A$ is not invertible, then the  column space of $A$ is not maximal ($<n$ if $A$  is an $n\times n$ matrix) and so $Ax=0$ has more than one solution.

The rest is then clear.