# Prove that any $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> **Proposition.** Any $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^{n}$

My attempt:

Quoting definition from the book

> If vectors form a basis in $\mathbb R^{n}$ , then:
>
> 1. They are linearly independent.
> 2. They span $\mathbb R^{n}$

Since first requirement is actually the assumption that we make, we only need to show that vectors span $\mathbb R^{n}$

Consider arbitrary linearly independent vectors $\{\mathbf{v_{1}}, \mathbf{v_{2}}\,\cdots , \mathbf{v_{n}}\}$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$. We will have following linear combination

$$\tag 1k_{1}\mathbf{v_{1}} + k_{2}\mathbf{v_{2}} + ... + k_{n}\mathbf{v_{n}} = 0 $$

Where $k$ represent scalars, and in the linear combination above

$$k_{1} =  k_{2} ... = k_{n} = 0$$

The linear combination $(1)$ can be rewritten as the following linear system

$$\bf Ax = O$$

where $\mathbf{A} = (\mathbf{v}_{1},\mathbf{v}_{2},...,\mathbf{v}_{n})$ and $\mathbf {x} = (k_{1},k_{2}, \cdots , k_{n})^{T}$

By applying following theorem (Because it is a bit lengthy, I tried to prove it in another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359496/prove-that-if-linear-system-bf-ax-o-has-a-unique-solution-then-for-arbitra/3359520#3359520))

> **Theorem.** If linear system $\bf Ax = O$ ($\bf A$ is $n$ by $n$  square matrix) has a unique solution, then for arbitrary vector $\bf b$, $\bf Ax = b$ will have a unique solution.

Since we *do* have $n$ by $n$ matrix (each column of $\bf A$ represents $n$-dimensional vector $\bf v$, and we have $n$ of them) we can deduce that, for arbitrary vector $\bf b$, there *always* will be $\bf x$ such that:

$$\mathbf {Ax} = \tag 2 k_{1}\mathbf{v_{1}} + k_{1}\mathbf{v_{2}} + ... + k_{1}\mathbf{v_{n}} = \bf b $$

In other words, any vector in $\mathbb R^{n}$ can be written as the linear combination of the vectors $\{\mathbf{v_{1}}, \mathbf{v_{2}}\,\cdots , \mathbf{v_{n}}\}$. Therefore, we conclude that vectors $\{\mathbf{v_{1}}, \mathbf{v_{2}}\,\cdots , \mathbf{v_{n}}\}$ span $\mathbb R^{n}$, and because they are linearly independent, they also form a basis for  $\mathbb R^{n}$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: I'm not a supporter of citing other theorems to prove a statement if the theorem actually proves it.

Comment: @Wuestenfux, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3359496/prove-that-if-linear-system-bf-ax-o-has-a-unique-solution-then-for-arbitra/3359520#3359520, the post would be too long if I included it in

Comment: @Wuestenfux I edited my post to mention this. And besides, the theorem alone doesn't clearly prove the proposition. Hence more explanation is required. And this is where the mistake can be.